# Sandbox access in Australia

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Since the developer site update the other day, I have lost access to the sandbox.
I was literally using it an hour before the update.

I tried to retrieve my password, but my account is no longer found.
I tried to set up a new account, and it's telling me that I need to have a US registered business in order to sign up.

So, my question is, what does the rest of the world do when they need to test their site?
Am I missing something?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: I'd contact PayPal support and ask them that question.

Comment: Unfortunatly, you need a PayPal accountt to contact PayPal, and they have removed ours, and prevented us from signing up!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Got it. PayPay support have said to create a dummy account. In other words, lie about having an American business. Once you've done that, go to applications, then sandbox accounts, and import the data using your old sandbox credentials!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It appears to be even worse than stated. They appear to have 'integrated' the Sandbox login with PayPal account logins. So you have to have a live PayPal account. In other words developers must also be CFOs in their organizations, or else must be using PayPal as a means of exchange themselves, otherwise they don't exist.

Truly incredible.

Not to mention having cut off arbitrary numbers of existing developers in mid-stream.

Comment: That's incredible. Especially since their plan is to roll it out "over the year".

Does anyone know of a work around? I just need to test transactions, and that's it.
I guess I could use test credit cards, but that would still be using the Paypal API, so it may be a waste of time.

Comment: I logged this with them last week, still no response. Not acceptable.